# MySQL pick pieces of data which have the same value in their column

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to pick both rows from database which have the same value. But that value is not known by user.
For example:

```
name   surname   idd
Will   Smith     8 
Jaden  Smith     8
Jed    Stiles    55
Charlie Sheen    55
```

So It would pick Will Smith and Jaden Smith and echo it in first row cause their idd is the same. And it would pick Jed Stiles and Charlie Sheen and echo it in second row cause their idd is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this? This query is still untested.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(`name`, ' ', `surname`)), COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM TBL GROUP BY idd HAVING cnt > 1
```

Comment: what is this GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(`name`, ' ', `surname`))

Comment: `CONCAT(name, ' ', surname)` is to construct a full name string. For example: Will Smith. `GROUP_CONCAT` connect all the full name within the same group separated by comma. In this case, group row with the same idd. For example: Will Smith, Jaden Smith

Comment: Since you only want find rows with duplicated `idd`, I eliminate row that does not have duplicated idd by using `HAVING cnt > 1`